# Performance testing of native iOs apps

Tags: ios, performance

I have a native iOS app developed in house which need to be tested for performance.  Any suggestions regarding this like the approach, tools that can be used for this etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree with the notion that if iPhone 3GS works it works with everything above. I have done lots of testing across devices and versions of iOS and find bugs all the time that don't manifest on iOS 5 but will on 6 or 7. Bugs that happen on one device but not another because of performance differs in the hardware.

I would suggest that identify who your primary audience is and what devices they are likely to be using. What device/os combinations do you care the most about making a "legendary" experience. Do you want to limit/complicate yourself to supporting an older SDK or simply build against the latest and greatest?

Once you have these questions answered, get a few physical devices if possible for "real" testing, and then use simulator to flush out and iOS version bugs. A good spread might be an iPad 2, iPad Air, iPhone 4, and iPhone 5 or 5s.

Hope this helps.